# Is it possible to find the source code for a GUI in R?

Tags: r

I want to look at the source code for a couple of GUIs in R to see how they work. Very new to GUIs in R (hence wanting to have a look at a few to get an idea), and I'm not sure if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to `shiny` Apps, you can open most Apps with RStudio Cloud and see the source code. Try it first with the examples at:https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/#user-showcase

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are referring to `shiny`-based interfaces. If so, starting with the official documentation is a good start. The official website inlcudes a showcase gallery, which includes source code of apps: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/#user-showcase